# Haproxy exporter unable to fetch data

Tags: grafana, prometheus, centos-6.9

I am using haproxy_exporter in prometheus and add prometheus as a datasource in grafana and the haproxy plugin using prometheus as a datasource in order to fetch haproxy stats and shown in grafana server. And i am not able to get the output from it.
When i run below command, I am getting error **invalid URL port**.

`./haproxy_exporter --no-haproxy.ssl-verify --haproxy.scrape-uri="http://user:$(cat pwfile)192.168.1.10:10000/haproxy/stats;csv"`

OUTPUT:

```
INFO[0000] Starting haproxy_exporter (version=0.9.0, branch=master, revision=0cae8ee3e3f3b7c517db2cc68f386672d8b1b6a7)  source=haproxy_exporter.go:495
INFO[0000] Build context (go=go1.10.1, user=root@rlinux57, date=20180724-16:08:06)  source=haproxy_exporter.go:496
INFO[0000] Listening on :9101                            source=haproxy_exporter.go:521


**ERRO[0013] Can't scrape HAProxy: Get http://admin:abEDokA("192.168.1.10:10000/haproxy/stats;csv: invalid URL port abEDokA("192.168.1.10:10000"  source=haproxy_exporter.go:315**
```

And when i placed **@** sign between password and IP address, such as `./haproxy_exporter --no-haproxy.ssl-verify --haproxy.scrape-uri="http://admin:abEDokA("@192.168.1.10:10000/haproxy/stats;csv"`
It gives below error:

```
INFO[0000] Starting haproxy_exporter (version=0.9.0, branch=master, revision=0cae8ee3e3f3b7c517db2cc68f386672d8b1b6a7)  source=haproxy_exporter.go:495
INFO[0000] Build context (go=go1.10.1, user=root@rlinux57, date=20180724-16:08:06)  source=haproxy_exporter.go:496
FATA[0000] parse http://admin:abEDokA("@192.168.1.10:10000/haproxy/stats;csv: net/url: invalid userinfo  source=haproxy_exporter.go:500
```

And my prometheus settings are:

```
  - job_name: 'haproxy'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.
   static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9101']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `@` in there and you might need to get rid of the `"` in your password. Maybe simply escaping it (`\"`) could work, but the second error message suggests haproxy_exporter somehow correctly receives the URL as `http://admin:abEDokA("@192.168.1.10:10000/haproxy/stats;csv` but is then unable to parse it.

Yup, according to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt, `"` is not a valid character in a URL. You may get around it by using its escape, `%22`.

Comment: Yes it's working with `%22`:

`http://admin:abEDokA(%22@192.168.1.10:10000/haproxy/stats;csv`